# Am I allowed to disclose to my interviewers that I am looking for a new job because my current company is in financial trouble? (Philippines)

Tags: interviewing, job-search, philippines

Related to this question: [Can I disclose my company's financial troubles when applying for new jobs (UK)?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/55404/can-i-disclose-my-companys-financial-troubles-when-applying-for-new-jobs-uk?lq=1)

But I am asking for a Philippine standpoint. If I am allowed to, if it is generally in poor taste, etc.

Basically, I am leaving because they could not pay me consistently, and are ignoring some of my messages besides. So now I am job searching.

Though Philippine law lets employees go of their contract obligations with their employer if employer could not pay consistently, hiring managers generally view applicants with prematurely-finished contracts with suspicion. That's why I am looking for a job below radar, at least until my contract ends or if I see a compelling, emergency reason to leave.

If I am not allowed to disclose to my prospective employers about the payroll issues of my would-be former employer, can I say something like?

> I love the work environment with [company], I love the culture, the challenge in solving problems. However, my needs have increased (which is true, I am racking up debt trying to live), and their compensation package sadly falls short of my expectations.

Thanks!

Comment: @mcknz I localized my question because the answers unique to my place might be radically different than generally, in the UK/US standpoint.

Comment: Agreed there may be a cultural component, but I believe it's universal that employers value employees who have motivation related to the company and the work. In other words, if asked why, I would not lead off with salary.

Comment: @mcknz okay then thank you. Will review the related question.

Comment: @JennyTengsonMandani - localisation isn't a reason to duplicate the question,  we're a global site so answers should really be applicable anywhere. I know the other question mentions the UK,  but that probably would be better being edited than a new similar question raised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the interviewer asks you why you're looking for a new job simply say, "I am looking for a stable position in my career." That wouldn't be lying at all.

Don't talk bad about your company or say they're having financial troubles.

Comment: +1 Unless it is public knowledge that your company is in financial trouble, you should never talk about it outside the company. Doing so is a breach of company confidentiality.

Comment: Unless that interviewer is only looking to fill in some blank space on their standard interview form, that sot of response is unlikely to satisfy them ...

Comment: Keep in mind the OP is having trouble even getting paid. It is perfectly acceptable to communicate concern about the long term viability of the job as the reason for seeking a new position as long as it is not made into drama. People do it ALL THE TIME with no repercussions.